# Javascript if expression evaluation

Tags: javascript

I was wondering when the Javascript `if` expression actually evaluates to `false` and when to `true`. When is the `if` statement `false`, and **is that true for all JS interpreters**?

I guess the condition is `false` on

- `false`
- `undefined`
- `null`
- `0`

otherwise `true`. Is that correct for all implementations (tested in Safari/WebKit console), or am I better off with explicit checking like `(typeof a  === "undefined")`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following values will evaluate to false:

- false
- undefined
- null
- 0
- NaN
- the empty string ("")

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Statements#if...else_Statement

Comment: Thank you! Did overlook that!

Comment: Just to know -- What is the order of evaluation in multiple JS if() conditions? Left to right or right to left?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for variable existence, and `a` is not declared anywhere in your script, `typeof a === 'undefined'` is the way, *or* you can use `if (!window.a)`. Otherwise a ReferenceError is thrown.

Your guessing seems to be correct. An empty string and NaN also evaluate to `false` (or, as some like it `falsy`). The fact that 0 evaluates to `false` may be tricky, but it's handy too, in statements like `while (i--)` (if `i` has the value of 0 it evaluates to `false` and the while loop stops).